# PHP - Show JSON array in html table

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a response from a website as

```
[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}...]
```

My code is

```
$json = '[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach($json_decoded as $result){
...
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

What is the issue here?

How can I show as table in html table?

Comment: Have you checked that the string is valid json?

Comment: try foreach($json as $result){...}

Comment: I just copied and pasted that and it worked for me...

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan - you can't loop over a string - `$json_decoded` is correct.

Comment: @Peter,yep, sorry. I didnt see that single quotes before the array, Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to access the parts of $result, they are an object so you need to use $result->name not $result['name']

Comment: You should post real data as this will work without problems. Either your json is invalid or the structure is not like you have shown.

Comment: Agree with @jeroen - your code above works perfectly fine, I feel there is something you are not showing us.

Comment: I am having trouble in implementing the data inside foreach loop @PeterFeatherstone

Comment: @Priyamanu. I have posted an answer and provided with a clear explanation. Share thought on that

Comment: @Priyamanu. added the code to display the data in the HTML table to. Have a check at my code explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code works perfectly fine - just testetd it on a local machine

```
<?php
    $json = '[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}]';
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json);
    foreach($json_decoded as $result){
      print_r($result);
    }
  ?>
```

To output your stuff as table, use this:

```
<?php
        $json = '[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}]';
        $json_decoded = json_decode($json);
        echo '<table>';
        foreach($json_decoded as $result){
          echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$result->name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$result->phone.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$result->email.'</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
      ?>
```

Make sure that your JSON string doesn't have any syntax errors... if yes the json_decode will fail and the foreach() loop throws an error.

Comment: Thank you. Actually my json data had some errors in its values. I cleaned up the data and the code worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

The code what you have mentioned in the question works perfect and i am getting the output as required in the table to. But ensure a check whether the `json_encode()` is correct so that the `foreach` error hides away.

You can also use this method as i have suggested over here to print in the table .

You have to apply `TRUE` to `json_decode` statement since the std_object array is pertaining to that so that it will lead to confusions in printing the array values.

**json_decode()**

```
Syntax: json_decode($jsonstring,TRUE);
```

json_decode — Decodes a JSON string

Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$json = '[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json,TRUE);
foreach($json_decoded as $result){
    echo $result['name']; // this wil output the values as xxxyyyzzz
}
?>
```

**Output of print_r() without TRUE in json_decode() statement:**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => xxx [phone] => 123 [email] => a@a.com ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => yyy [phone] => 456 [email] => b@a.com ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => zzz [phone] => 678 [email] => c@a.com ) )
```

**Output of print_r() with using TRUE in json_decode() Statement**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => xxx [phone] => 123 [email] => a@a.com ) [1] => Array ( [name] => yyy [phone] => 456 [email] => b@a.com ) [2] => Array ( [name] => zzz [phone] => 678 [email] => c@a.com ) )
```

Hence the output for the code above will be as follows.

```
xxxyyyzzz
```

With-no trouble you can loop through the `foreach` data and you can print using it.

Print the data in the table you can follow the code as mentioned below.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"name":"xxx","phone":"123","email":"a@a.com"},{"name":"yyy","phone":"456","email":"b@a.com"},{"name":"zzz","phone":"678","email":"c@a.com"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json,TRUE);
?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
<?php
    foreach($json_decoded as $result){
        ?>
        <tr>
            
            <td><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

I hope so your need would be fulfilled by my solution.

Happy coding :)

Comment: This does not address the problem that the OP is having at all: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: No possibility at all. @jeroen. This code will work to the best and efficient. I have proof and i have tested it. Dont blame like this you are getting errors like this and so on.

Comment: It will work or else you show me where you are getting error in my code. I have showed all the results with proof that i get.

Comment: You're not making any sense, the OP has an error and has posted a question. This answer does not address that problem.

Comment: I have tested and nope error shows up with this code that i have done. That is the reason i have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Or else you blame me that i am bluffing. There are two methods to solve this. One is as mentioned by @Adrian Lambertz and the other method is as stated by me..

Comment: @jeroen. **Without using** `json_decode(TRUE)` you have to use @Adrian Lambertz method and by **using** `json_decode(TRUE)` you can use my method.

Comment: @jeroen. I have provided explanations about what toy have stated. Can you tell me if you need still more explanations on to this issue. Pls reveoke back the negative points that you have awarded. Since my approch to the question is correct.

Comment: @jeroen. Still you have not updated me with the reply . I have updated the answer that i have posted long back ago. Please revert me back with the reviews.